# When a user opens outlook desktop application they get an error 400 browser webpage that pops up

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

When a user opens an outlook desktop application, they get an error 400 browser webpage that pops up. Not sure if this is related to some new thing that Microsoft is trying to push or what.

[Screenshot of Error 400 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNobT.png)

But I have tried to disable all add-ins, repaired outlook, reinstalled outlook, tried opening outlook in safe mode.

Multiple users have started to report the same issue; it seems to be slowly being pushed out to new users over time...

I think I have narrowed it down to this:

If you go to File in Outlook, there is an option for Manage Add-ins: Manage and acquire Web Add-ins for Outlook. If I click on this on the computer of a user having the issue, it takes me to the browser and I get the same error 400 webpage.

[Screenshot of Manage Add-ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyZOJ.png)

I have been looking for a way to disable the web add-ins capability to see if I can then keep that web page from popping up when a user opens outlook. So far I have not found anything in my search regarding a policy or registry key that will completely disable the web add-ins function.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this by chance? Or any other ideas if anyone may think my thoughts on the matter are incorrect?

Comment: Does this issue only occur when the option is clicked?

Comment: It occurs when they open outlook and when clicking on that button, also occurs when they are crafting an email. Other than that the emails work fine.

Comment: Did [this result](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/fix-http-400-bad-request-error-in-exchange-server-environment/) come up in your websearches for "error 400 outlook office"?

Comment: it did not, or i overlooked it.

Comment: We use Office 365 and one of the users is having something similar happen. When they use the Outlook desktop application it just seems to randomly try to open Outlook on the web. The error itself may be due to OWA being turned off for the user? I have no clue why it is trying to open OWA in the first place though :(

Comment: Apparently Microsoft is aware of the issue

Answer (score 0):

This article is probably the explanation, the suggested fix worked for me

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-unexpectedly-opens-a-browser-window-if-owa-is-disabled-4c915e88-0654-4f77-8daa-a624600dc718

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am also watching the Microsoft Forums, it looks like they are aware of the issue and are working on a fix... if they ever do actually fix it....